# What explicitly is the "adjunction" isomorphism $Hom_C(A,C)\to Hom_B(A,Hom_C(B,C))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Suppose $B$ and $C$ are commutative rings, $A$ a $B$-algebra, and $B$ is a $C$-module. What exactly is the "adjunction" isomorphism 
$$Hom_C(A,C)\to Hom_B(A,Hom_C(B,C))?$$

Given $A\to C$, it needs to be composed with a morphism $C\to Hom_C(B,C)$. I know $Hom_C(C,B)\simeq B$, but that doesn't seem to work here.

Here also $A$ is a finitely generated projective $B$-module, and $B$ is a finitely generated projective $C$-module.

Comment: There's no reason for this to be an isomorphism-perhaps you've misread something? Consider $A=B=C^2$, where the left-hand side is $C^2$ and the right-hand, $C^4$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I went back and doublechecked everything, and that's what it says. If $A=B$, wouldn't the right hand side still be isomorphic to $Hom_{C^2}(C^2,Hom_C(C^2,C))\simeq Hom_{C^2}(C^2,C^2)\simeq C^2$?

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the adjunction in question is likely the classic tensor hom adjunction $\text{Hom}_C(A \otimes_R B, X) \cong \text{Hom}_R(A, \text{Hom}_C(B, X))$. Where all the objects in question have the appropriate structures such that this makes sense (X is a module over C, A is a module over R, B is a bi-module over both R and C, and R, C are just rings).

The statement you are trying to prove then follows from the observation that if $A$ is a $B$ algebra, then $A \otimes_B B \cong A$ as $C$-modules, taking $X = C, R = B$ above. This is a very simple thing to show if you understand the tensor product.

Edit: the explicit map takes a $\phi \in \text{Hom}_C(A \otimes_B B, C)$ and sends this to the map $\psi \in \text{Hom}_B(A, \text{Hom}_C(B, C))$ where $\psi$ sends $a \to \phi_a$ where $\phi_a(b) = \phi(a \otimes b)$. That this mapping is $B$-linear and an isomorphism is once again not hard.

Comment: One should say that this is called an adjunction because it shows that the functors $F: Mod_B \to Mod_C$ given by $F(X) = X \otimes_B Y$ and $G: Mod_C \to Mod_B$ given by $G(X) = Hom_C(Y, X)$ are an adjoint pair when $Y$ is a $C, B$ bimodule.

Comment: Ah thanks, I recall this adjunction.

Comment: I think  for $A\otimes B \cong A$  one needs $B$ to be unital i.e., to have an identity element (which I am sure was assumed). While $A\otimes B \rightarrow A$ can always be defined ($a\otimes b \mapsto ab$ ), without $1$ going the other way $A\rightarrow A\otimes B$ ( $ a \mapsto a\otimes ?$ ) is an issue. This isn't pure pedantry for the fun of it - e.g.,  see p. 124 of Cartier's ariticle in Aut forms, reps, and L-Functions, for Frobenius reciprocity in the context of Hecke algebras (an operator alg. with convolution as mult)

Answer (score -3):

The actual isomorphism is (in category theory):

```
hom(AxB,C) = hom(A,hom(B,C))
```

It is normally known as "currying". (the hom's are in Set, not in C or B)

I'm a little confused why they call it "adjunction", since that means slightly different thing, but the word doesnt seem to explain your isomorphism.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, not sure what this is all about then.

Comment: This is basically the first example of an adjunction, so I'm not sure what your last sentence means. The homs can certainly be taken over $C$, if you replace $A\times B$ with $A\otimes B$.

Comment: I mean, I needed to make too many changes to the original, so it's unsure if the question means currying isomorphism or something else; the word "adjunction" didn't clarify it enough.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely isn't the currying isomorphism from sets.